# Showing just one instance of a class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I've googled and so searched this, but to no avail (probably poor search skills).

My problem is probably pretty simple, I simply want the mouseover event to only show the containing div (.action) when the list item is moused over (ui-state-default).

Here's the Markup

```
<ul id="column-2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">feature
        <div class="action">
            <img src="delete.png" class="delete" alt="Delete this Story">
            <br />
            <img src="duplicate.png" class="delete" alt="Duplicate this Story">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">forward
        <div class="action">
            <img src="delete.png" class="delete" alt="Delete this Story">
            <br />
            <img src="duplicate.png" class="delete" alt="Duplicate this Story">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the JavaScript

```
$(function() {  
    $(".ui-state-default").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".action").show();
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(".action").hide();
        });
});
```

Now I realise that this is going to show every occurrence of .action - but how can I make sure it only shows it within it's parent li? I've tried using the jquery parent/child arguements but have failed miserably.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $(".ui-state-default).mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find(".action").show();
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find(".action").hide();
  });
});
```

Or just use the hover() event:

```
$(function() {
  $(".ui-state-default").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".action").show();
  }, function() {
    $(this).find(".action").hide();
  });
});
```

Instead of:

```
$(this).find(".action")
```

you can also do:

```
$(this).children(".action")
```

or any number of other ways of selecting it.

Comment: damn! Never thought of find() at all :( Thanks very much Cletus

Comment: Yeah jQuery is a funny one.  It takes a little while to start to realize what you can do with the tools.  Love it though. :)

Comment: Indeed, the sheer community support and vast documentation/blogs on it are amazing. 

Also, hover seems to of processed a little faster than mouseenter/leave - interesting.

Answer (score 3):

You should constrain ".action" to current context (the list item you're hovering):

```
$(function (){
  $(".ui-state-default").hover(
    var listItem = this;
    function (){
      $(".action", listItem).show();         
    }
    ,
    function (){
      $(".action", listItem).hide();         
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks SebaGR, however Cletus was a little faster ;) +vote for another correct answer though